What will be the moral and social consequences of knowing that the universe is deterministic?
A deterministic universe in theory where observing every interaction between particles in the universe would allow you to predict the future. A deterministic universe will be the one without any free will. What would be the social consequences if everyone starts believing in it?

Questions about determinism, indeterminism and free will have been discussed several times on this site. What did you find out until now by your own resesarch? - See also online encyclopedia like https://plato.stanford.edu/ or IPE https://iep.utm.edu/

Do you mean "what would be the social consequences if they believe this and they're wrong"? If they're right, them starting to believe something (for suitably illusory them and believe) has changed nothing about how things were always going to be since the beginning of time.

I think "how does / would seriously believing that everything anyone does is determined affect human behavior as it relates to social consequences?" is a good question but I think it belongs on Psychology SE.

A good question was previously asked with multiple sociology references on this very topic.  See: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/84518/if-free-will-is-proven-illusory-is-there-a-case-for-suppressing-the-finding

Note that your presumption, that a) the world is knowable, and b) it is deterministically predictable, are both untrue, per quantum mechanics.  The Heisenberg uncertainty principle makes the current state of the universe undefinable, below the uncertainty constant.  And decay times for a quantum particle are -- unpredictable in principle for all QM interpretations.  There is an alternative theory, Bohmian Mechanics, which IS deterministic, but it requires knowing the state of everything in the universe at this instant, including parts of the universe beyond the light cone from the big bang.

Even BM, however, is constrained by Heisenberg's uncertainly principle.  And Chaos theory shows that micro events are leverageable up to macro scales, so Heisenberg uncertainty at the quantum level, leads to chaotic uncertainty at the macro level.

"In theory, there is no difference between determinism and computability. In practice, there is" - Not Yogi Berra

Note that "A deterministic universe will be the one without any free will" is a contested claim. Some (compatibilists) define free will to be compatible with determinism. Free will through indeterminism would be libertarian free will, but some consider that definition to be incoherent and consider randomness (the only form of indeterminism we can even conceive of) to mean your agency is removed, not that you have more agency.

@Dcleve Given your assertion that Bohmian Mechanics is not an interpretation of QM, you might want to contend with the fact that the first sentence of the Wikipedia page is "Bohmian mechanics ... is an interpretation of quantum mechanics", and it's listed under "interpretations of QM". The SEP is similar. I would recommend you edit Wikipedia if it's wrong, but I don't want to advise putting wrong things on Wikipedia

@NotThatGuy  Wikipedia says it is not a reliable source:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_is_not_a_reliable_source.   I advise you to choose better references. Bohmian Mechanics is not an "interpretation" of QM, because it makes different predictions. https://settheory.net/Bohm Therefore, it is a different theory.

@Dcleve I was going to ask whether Bohm's original paper introducing the idea is a good enough reference for you (but maybe you'd take issue with it saying "quantum theory" instead of "quantum mechanics"). But then I noticed that the very first sentence in your own link says "the de Broglie-Bohm interpretation of quantum mechanics". Although it's a bit concerning that you seem to think the criticism of a topic on the blog of some random PhD is a "good" source for understanding what that topic is about.

SEP - Fatalism:
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fatalism/

Though the word “fatalism” is commonly used to refer to an attitude of resignation in the face of some future event or events which are thought to be inevitable, philosophers usually use the word to refer to the view that we are powerless to do anything other than what we actually do. This view may be argued for in various ways: by appeal to logical laws and metaphysical necessities; by appeal to the existence and nature of God; by appeal to causal determinism. When argued for in the first way, it is commonly called “Logical fatalism” (or, in some cases, “Metaphysical fatalism”); when argued for in the second way, it is commonly called “Theological fatalism”. When argued for in the third way it is not now commonly referred to as “fatalism” at all, and such arguments will not be discussed here.


What will be the moral and social consequences of knowing that the universe is deterministic?

